# How to use NSUrlSession with WKViewView for client certificate authentication

Tags: xamarin.ios, wkwebview, nsurlsession

I am trying to implement a WKViewView that supports client certificate authentication with Xamarin.IOS. I found samples with UIWebView that is now deprecated. But I can't find any sample with WKViewView. How to use NSUrlSessionHandler or NSUrlSessionDelegate with WKViewView ?

Comment: `WKWebView` in iOS is based on WebKit . So it doesn't support some behavior in UIWebView . You could use `WKNavigationDelegate` and implement the method `- webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler:
`  .Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate?language=objc

Comment: I'm new to Xamarin. How can I use WKNavigationDelegate with WKWebViewRenderer ?

Comment: Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/174336/how-to-implement-wkwebview-in-xamarin-forms .